# WCF Service . Setting response type to XML/JSON using the Accept HTTP Header?

Tags: c#, xml, json, wcf, serialization

I want my WCF service to accept and respond to requests in JSON or XML. 
I thought that WCF was supposed to automatically interpret the response type based on the Accept header that the client specifies. 
However in my client request I specify the accept header to be application/json but I receive an XML response.

This is my service definition:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/GetChecks", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
Check[] GetChecks(MyCustomObj Object);
```

Im making the request here :

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
    client.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";

    string response = client.UploadString(endpoint, JSONRequestString);   
    // Response is XML
}
```

I know I can make two endpoints and specify one as XML and the other as JSON but id rather not do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you have on server set a property automaticFormatSelectionEnabled to true

You can do it either in config

```
<webHttpEndpoint> 
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true"  
                                automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/> 
</webHttpEndpoint>
```

or in code:

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof (PricingService));
var beh = new WebHttpBehavior { AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled = true };
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (IPricingService), new WebHttpBinding(), uri)
            .Behaviors.Add(beh);
```